# how to put file in src java folder in java 8

Tags: java, path, nio

I need to generate a JAVA file which will be used by the other JAVA file within the same project.

This creation will happen while building the project. Because the class is being used within the same project, hence I think it should be placed under src/main/java only.

The issue is from Paths API, I am not able to go to this location directly. I have to hard code the absolute path to my file for creating that class.

Is there any way by which I can use a relative path to create a file?

Also , Should file be there in src folder at first place?

Comment: "Should file be there in src folder at first place?" possibly not. What does the generated file do?

Comment: @priyas Can you paste first few lines of your generated file? Basically till the line final class MyGeneratedClass { ......}